# Shelf life of dried egg pasta & pasta hanger or fridge?

Tags: pasta

I have gleaned that fresh pasta (egg and flour) can be "left on the counter to dry". My question is, how soon will the dried fresh pasta go bad. Secondly, where should dry pasta be stored? In the pantry or in the fridge?

When in the pantry, maybe twirled on itself and inside a container. My problem with pasta hangers is that it attracts ants.

Comment: The freezer is your best storage option.  Freeze flat, then bag.  Cook directly from frozen.

Comment: When I tried to look that up, I got results between [two years](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17131) and [30 years](https://www.leaf.tv/articles/can-dried-egg-noodles-expire/) without a fridge. That's consistent with what I think I know, but not quite enough to post an *answer* about safety.

Comment: Odd that it's attracting ants .. are you using any kind of sugar (or anything with natural sugars) in your recipes? I had an ant infestation at one point but they never went  near my butternut linguini.

Comment: @Molot maybe you've looked up "dry" pasta (?) i.e. one that's made with flour and water.

Comment: @Tim Post it really does. Could be the species in my backyard. Nope, no sugar. Just flour and whole eggs.

Comment: @wearashirt No. [\[1\]](https://www.leaf.tv/articles/can-dried-egg-noodles-expire/), [\[2\]](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17131)

Answer (score 3):

The most accurate answer is going to depend quite a bit on your environment, the following things are factors:

- How humid is the air where you dry it?
- How *clean* (e.g. absence of mold and particles, dust, etc) is the air where you dry it? You'd be surprised how some dirty air ducts can contaminate a room.
- The average temperature of the room

There's also the moisture content of the pasta itself to consider. Under ideal conditions (semi-warm, relatively dry and reasonably clean air), pasta that has been dried correctly can last for several weeks at room temperature on a vented tray covered with some wax or parchment paper. I try *very* hard to consume it within that period, ideally within a day or two of making it.

If you do need to store it longer, you want it in an evacuated container of some kind (vacuum sealed) and then freeze it. ***Make absolutely certain the pasta is completely dry or the crystallization of the remaining moisture is going to affect it very negatively***.

If you need to make a lot *well* ahead of time, consider using a bit less egg than your recipe calls for, kneading more, and then simply refrigerating the pasta in an otherwise evacuated container (plastic bag, etc) similar to how you'd purchase fresh pasta at the grocery store. It can stay refrigerated in that manner for up to a couple of months, and you can dry it fully prior to using it.

It's hard to write a blanket 'safe' answer here too, as oils you might add to your recipe could be closer to being rancid than you think - use common sense above everything else and rely on your sense of smell :)

In short, if you're going to end up freezing it ... you're kind of defeating the purpose of making it fresh to begin with, a good brass-cut pre-made commercial durum would almost be a better idea at that point. But if you do have to freeze it, try to do so in the absence of air and moisture, or you'll end up with something that sort of defeated the purpose of making it fresh to begin with.

Comment: Very thorough response, most of which I agree with.  However, it is common practice to freeze fresh pasta, both for storage and for handling purposes.  Quality is not compromised. Further, dried, durum pasta is a different product used for different purposes.

Comment: Im in S.E. Asia. humidity fluctuates, and temps are warm to just okay. I'm just surprised that the egg that hydrates the pasta doesn't cause it to rot much sooner than 24 hours (since you've said that it can last weeks?). I wonder if there's an answer that explains longevity, of course with variability to climate, as you've mentioned.